# Should we create [chartio] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-creation-request

This tag could be used for people with questions specific to using Chartio, a self-service business intelligence (BI) tool to work in one of two basic modes. Users have the choice between the drag-and-drop interactive mode or the Structured Query Langiuage (SQL) mode. While SQL mode is meant for expert users, most business users will probably want to go with the drag-and-drop functionality.

More information found here:

- https://chartio.com
- https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2497158,00.asp

[List of questions that could benefit from this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chartio).

Comment: Is there already a question warranting such a tag?

Comment: Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51270713/checking-chartio-filter-for-empty-string-sql-case-statement

Comment: As well as these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chartio

Comment: Are there any such questions yet? Tags are created on an as-needed basis, so if there are no questions, there is no tag. If you have a question about it, feel free to ask one and *then* request the tag creation. If a tag isn't used on at least one question, it is deleted within 24 hours.

Comment: I would suggest pointing to the tool's own website rather than a magazine article...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, thanks, I just updated the description!

Answer (score 3):

The tag [chartio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chartio) has been created.

Please suggest an appropriate [tag usage guidance and tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/133697) if you are able to.